# Numerical solution of differential equaition using gradient flow?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I have a differential equation taken from eq(5.12) of this [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1709.06583).
$$-4r\dot{r}^2 + 2 r^2 \ddot{r}+\frac{4}{r^2}\dot{r}^3\sin^3(\xi)\cos(\xi)+\dot{r}^3 r^2 \sin(\xi)=0$$
Where $\xi$ is a variable of the function $r=r(\xi)$ with conditions $\lim_{\xi\rightarrow 0}r(\xi)=\infty$, $r(\pi)=0$. In the paper, the authors claim that one can solve this with gradient flow.

I tried to look up a numerical method that uses gradient flow but can not find a good reference for this method (I am completely a noob in a numerical method so this might be a well-known method?). If anyone is familiar with such a numerical method, It would be very helpful if you could direct me to a reference for this.

Thank you

Comment: A quick scan of the cited paper, its references, and their references indicates that the more common name is "[gradient descent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_descent)".  This is a collection of methods.  Knowing which detailed method and what parameters were chosen requires more information than is present in this Question or in the cited paper.

Comment: @EricTowers Thank you. I will read about the gradient descent method.